# Change model observable inside custom handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I wrote the following custom bind handler which shows a jquery-ui autocomplete list. After selecting the element I want to change the given observable value which is given by options.value but there is no change when the select function enters.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autocomplete = {
    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());               

        $(element).autocomplete(
                {
                    minLength : 2,
                    autoFocus : true,
                    source : function(request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url : options.source,
                            data : {
                                term : request.term
                            },
                            dataType : "json",
                            type : "GET",
                            success : function(data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select : function(event, ui) {
                        var selectedItem = ui.item;
                        options.value(selectedItem.name);
                    }
                });
    }
};

<input data-bind="autocomplete: { 
    value: myView().parent_name,
    source: '/data/autocomplete'
}" 
type="text" class="form-control">
```

**Edit 1**

I tried the binding from the comment but I still have an issue.

```
model.autocomplete = function(searchTerm, callback){
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/data/autocomplete",
        data: {term: searchTerm}
    }).done(callback);
};
```

The input looks like this:

```
    <input data-bind="jqAuto: { 
        value: myView().parent_name,
        source: myView().autocomplete,
        labelProp: 'name',
        valueProp: 'parent_name'
    }" 
    type="text" class="form-control">
```

This doesn't change myView().parent_name

**Edit 2**

I think I know whats the problem now. I made a much simpler test file like this one:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete/master/build/knockout-jqAutocomplete.js"></script>

<h1>Testpage</h1>
<input data-bind="jqAuto : {
        source: sub().autocomplete,
        value: sub().id,
        labelProp: 'name',
        valueProp: 'id'
    }"></input>
<button data-bind="click: sub().output">ok</button>
<button data-bind="click: reset">reset</button>

<script>
function getData() {
    var data = [
        {
            name: "Test1",
            id: 1
        },
        {
            name: "Test2",
            id: 2
        },{
            name: "Test3",
            id: 3
        }       
    ];
    return data;
}

function Submodel() {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable("");
    self.id = ko.observable(null);

    self.autocomplete = function(searchTerm, callback) {
        callback(getData());
    };

    self.output = function(){
        alert(self.id());
    };
}

function PageModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.sub = ko.observable(new Submodel());

    self.reset = function(){
        self.sub(new Submodel());
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new PageModel());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is a submodel which is cleared at some point but this seems to invalidate the binding. Until the point I press the reset button, everything works fine. Is there any solution to update the binding after reset. I need this reset because I want to use a dialog with the model without using the dialog binding and without cleaning every variable by hand.

Comment: Make sure you're not reinventing the wheel: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete

Comment: Now that you've tried the jqAutocomplete binding: show us the `myView` viewmodel and what `parent_name` and `name` are.

Comment: The only thing myModel() defined is parent_name = ko.observable(null) at the moment. I looked into the code of jqAuto and it seems, that this applies the whole json node instead of just parent_name

Answer (score 1):

Based on the (minimal) code you've provided and your answers to my question in the comments I might be able to help by showing a working example.

Most important takeaways:

- You'll have to read through the differences between `valueProp`, `inputProp` and `labelProp`: they are used to define what you want to *store in your viewmodels* versus what you want to *show to the user*.
- Make sure the data your `autocomplete` method returns has the props you specify

Notes to try the example:

- I didn't include the css, so it's ugly
- I've used the strings `"one"` to `"ten"` as example data. Type `o` or `e` or any other letter used in these words to get started.

```js
var Model = function() {
  return {
    parent_name: ko.observable(null),
    autocomplete: function(searchTerm, callback) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        callback(getData().filter(function(v) { 
          return v.name.includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
        }));
      }, 200);
    }
  };
};

var vm = {
  myView: ko.observable(new Model()),
  reset: () => vm.myView(new Model())
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

function getData() {
    return ["one", "two", "three", "four", 
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", 
            "nine", "ten"]
      .map(str => ({ name: str }));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete/master/build/knockout-jqAutocomplete.js"></script>

<p>
  <code>parent_name</code>’s value is: 
  <strong>
    <code data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(myView().parent_name())"></code>  
  </strong>
</p>


<!-- ko with: myView -->
<input data-bind="jqAuto: { 
        value: parent_name,
        source: autocomplete,
        labelProp: 'name',
        valueProp: 'name'
    }" type="text" class="form-control">
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: reset">reset</button>
```

Comment: Now I started debugging jqAutocomplete. In the config.select callback there is a call to options.value(ui.item.actual) where actual is the value i selected but the observable isn't set.

Comment: You'll have to show me some more than just saying "the observable isn't set"... I can't reproduce this, so you're probably doing something wrong elsewhere...

Comment: I think the problem is in the way you reference the `parent_name` in value. When `myView()` changes, the reference to the old `parent_name` observable remains. Try to place the binding inside a `with: sub` binding.